# VBA form control by variable name using a string

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a procedure that will re-load a listbox everytime a page is changed. I hope to use it any any scenario anything is changed down the road, but I am stuck on decalring the object variable for a listbox. Below is what I have:

```
Private Sub MultiPage1_Change()

Dim mpn As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
     mpn = Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Caption
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets(mpn)
     mpn = Replace(mpn, " ", "")
     mpn = "lbx_" & mpn
Dim lbx As Object
Set lbx = UserForm1.Controls(mpn)

variable_lbxload ws, mpn, lbx


End Sub
```

When I go to set the listbox it is set as "null". I copied this from another part of the code that works for me, but a little differently:

```
Dim lbx As Object
Set lbx = UserForm1.lbx_TodaysTasks
```

That one works, so I'm assuming declaring it as an object and setting the control name as the string is the right way to go about it. I still get "null" as my value. I have tried cycling through the multipage controls as so:

```
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Controls
    If ctrl.Name = mpn Then
        Set lbx = ctrl
    End If
Next ctrl
```

I have tried using Case:

```
Select Case mpn
    Case "TodaysTasks"
        Set lbx = Me.lbx_TodaysTasks
    Case "TaskList"
        Set lbx = Me.lbx_TaskList
    Case "TicklerFile"
        Set lbx = Me.lbx_TicklerFile
End Select
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I do want to say this is my first post. I have always been able to find what I'm doing wrong on the internet. This is the first one that has really stumped me though. Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
I saved closed and reopend and my case selection seems to have now worked. Any explanations or information on why I was having so much trouble would be great!